# How should I ask my Supervisor for a reference letter?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, application

I am a stem cell biology masters student in Japan and the lab I am in is a good lab. However, I have had struggles with my day to day life here in Japan. I find myself sad and even get depressed from time to time. It ends up affecting my attitude towards my experiments and school in general. The school program itself is not catered to international students and that adds to the daily struggles I face. The lab is the only good thing about this place but with the way everything is going...It truly affects everything that I do.

This is why I want to apply for a PhD elsewhere. I believe living in a more open and English speaking society will help. This means, I'd have to leave this good lab. That being said, I am failing and I am finding it hard to approach my supervisor to ask for a reference letter.
I keep on thinking that he might think something else and therefore ruin the good relationship we have.
How should I approach him to ask for a reference letter?

I have one more year of my Masters program. I have been in this lab for a year and 6 months now. I was a research student first then I became a Masters student. I was intending to continue here...but it seems that if I do so, it might take a huge toll on me.

Your advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: I would try to briefly and professionally explain the situation directly.  Why you think your supervisor wouldn't believe your reason?  I think a reasonable supervisor would be completely understanding about your situation.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kimball for the response! I will do as suggested.